# delay ring between two font style changing

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

I want to change font style of a control , for a short time. for example 2 secounds. I do like :

```
label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, label1.Font.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
for(int i=0,i<4000000,i++);
label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, label1.Font.Style | FontStyle.Regular);
```

but it doesn't work. what is the problem?

Comment: @Hesam Qodsi: +1 Beginner question but was useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this extension function?

```
public static class LabelExtensions
{
    public static Label BlinkText(this Label label, int duration)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.Interval = duration;
        timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
            {
                timer.Stop();
                label.Font = new Font(label.Font, label.Font.Style ^ FontStyle.Bold);
            };

        label.Font = new Font(label.Font, label.Font.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
        timer.Start();

        return label;
    }
}
```

Another interesting question comes to my mind, when writing this extension:
[Does it lead to a memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584009/lambdas-within-extension-methods-possible-memory-leak)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to wait two seconds. Try `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)` instead.

As for your problem: When you say: "It doesn't work", I assume that the font stays bold instead of returning to regular. Use this instead:

```
FontStyle style = label1.Font.Style;
label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, style | FontStyle.Bold); 
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, style);
```

To understand why your version did not work, look at the [MSDN documentation of the Enum type.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx)

Note that this will freeze your user interface for two seconds. You should try to avoid this. Have a look at the Timer class.

Comment: Thread.Sleep() function will freeze the form for too seconds. Its bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

As Jens said, a `Sleep` is much better than your 'busy-loop'.

a) that loop might be optimized away by the compiler
b) while busy waiting, the form can't update itself to show the first Font.

You might also need a `.Refresh()` just before the wait, to force the form (or just the Label) to repaint itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here I answered similar question.

[.NET: Best way to execute a lambda on UI thread after a delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565166/net-best-way-to-execute-a-lambda-on-ui-thread-after-a-delay/2566263#2566263)

I prefer using delegates and `BeginInvoke()` function.

Variant with `Timer`is easier for understanding and has no need to access to Control from another Thread.